# Deleted implicitly-declared copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, clang++, assignment-operator

According to the C++ reference on [Copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment):

> A defaulted copy assignment operator for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following is true
>
> T has a non-static data member of non-class type (or array thereof) that is const ...

I was hoping to create a case where I had a const class-type data member and a defaulted copy assignment operator not defined as deleted.  In doing so, I found a discrepancy between clang and gcc.  Consider the following code:

```
struct B {
  void operator=(const B&) const {}
};

struct A {
  const B b{};
  A& operator=(const A&) = default;
};

int main() {
  A a1{}, a2{};
  a1 = a2;       //only works with clang
  B b1{}, b2{};
  b1 = b2;       //works in both
}
```

When I compile this with `g++ -std=c++14` I get the following errors:

```
In member function ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)’:
error: non-static const member ‘const B A::b’, can’t use default assignment operator
note: synthesized method ‘A& A::operator=(const A&)’ first required here
```

This does, comma, however, compile with `clang`, as the reference seems to indicate that it should.  Am I in error?  Which compiler is correct?

I'm using `gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)` and `clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2`.

Comment: In general you want to use `C++` since that gives the question a much wider audience than C++ version specific tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that clang is right,

Although not yet confirmed, there is a [report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87063) on the subject for gcc
and as it was pointed out, the two rules relevant to this case don't apply

[[class.copy.assign]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#7)

> (7.2) a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof), or
>
> [...]
>
> (7.4) a direct non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) or a direct base class M that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution ([over.match]), as applied to find M's corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment operator.

Answer (score 3):

It sure looks like clang is correct, section [[class.copy.assign]p7](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#7) says:

> A defaulted copy/move assignment operator for class X is defined as
>   deleted if X has:
>
> - (7.1) a variant member with a non-trivial corresponding assignment operator and X is a union-like class, or
> - (7.2) a non-static data member of const non-class type (or array thereof), or
> - (7.3) a non-static data member of reference type, or
> - (7.4) a direct non-static data member of class type M (or array thereof) or a direct base class M that cannot be copied/moved because
>     overload resolution ([over.match]), as applied to find M's
>     corresponding assignment operator, results in an ambiguity or a
>     function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted assignment
>     operator.
>
> A defaulted move assignment operator that is defined as deleted is
>   ignored by overload resolution ([over.match], [over.over]).

and none of those cases hold.

Although I have to say a *const* copy assignment operator that returns void feels novel, the wording in [[class.copy.assign]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#1) sure seems to allow.

There is an open gcc bug report for a similar case [Const subobject with const assignment operator, but operator anyway deleted](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87063) with code as follows:

```
class bar
{
public:
    bar() {}

    bar const & operator=(bar const &) const
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

class foo
{
    bar const v;
};

int main()
{
    foo a;

    a = foo();
}
```

The reporter points out the same section as I do.